# Getting ClassCastException in android application

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

When the following activity is launched I a getting `ClassCastException`.

My Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bhupendra.myapplication.NewDialogsActivity"/>
```

My Activity class:

```
public class NewDialogsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        List<Fragment> tabs = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        tabs.add(UserFragment.getInstance());

        sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Users";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(NewDialogsActivity.this, DialogsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
}
```

I have used this theme in my code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.applyInsets(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:147)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:292)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2196)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1290)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5508)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can somebody help me what is wrong in this code.

```
minSdk=14
targetSdk=21
```

Comment: Which SDK level has device that you use to  test this example?

Comment: I am using API level 18 to check this example.

Comment: Your theme listing is truncated. Please post the entire theme, and please confirm that your activity is using that theme.

Comment: This theme is being used across application.

Comment: using appcompat 23.1.0?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reason:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.**support.v7**.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to
>   com.**android**.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams

so basically you should not mix "native" ActionBar with support lib's one. Choose and user either one or the other. Most likely you got incorrect `import` in your code so check your sources for `import com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout;` or so and remove and then either add correct `import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout;` or use "organize imports" function of your IDE and then ensure support lib's related ones are used (IDE shall ask)

Comment: No, I could not find answer till now.

Answer (score 0):

try extending [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html). It handles the app bar correctly